# AngularJS(JavaScript) and Keyboard Button Events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, keyboard-shortcuts, frontend

i have been working on web application. this app design and implement with ASP.NET MVC5 and EF6(BackEnd) and jquery 2.0 and AngularJS 1.5(FrontEnd) and SQL Server 2014 Instance. this software is type of Accounting Software.

The Problem was happen in the late is that,sometimes when a user log in into system and enter to document page and create new accounting document and type the name of document and through of type document name enter a space key, the key(space key) was not working and thrown off to other section of page element such as menu icon or etc.(and this Behavior occur when name of document is 2 part for example : This Document)

i don't know why this happen and i am confusing!!!

would anyone help me please.
thanks everyone.
excuse me for basic english writing.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What have you tried ? What is your code ?

Comment: i have trying to avoid lost space key behavior and when user push space key of keyboard the mouse cursor move next and create space between two words.